# Putting together a patchwork of plots by creating single plots by iterating over a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, foreach, patchwork

I want to write a for loop that produces a grid of plots (like when using patchwork). I want to run the loop for each item in the color_list dataframe and use it as an aesthetic.

I managed to write the loop but am unsure how to retain all the plots and put them together at the end.

```
color_list <- data.frame(color = c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow"))

for(row in 1:nrow(color_list)) {
  data %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y, color = color_list[row,]$color)) +
    geom_line()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create list of plots and pass it to any of the plotting library that you are using. For example, with `patchwork::wrap_plots` you can do :

```
do.call(patchwork::wrap_plots, lapply(color_list$color, function(x) {
  ggplot(data, aes(x=x,y=y)) +geom_line(color = x)
})) -> plot

plot
```

[image]

**data**

```
color_list <- data.frame(color = c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow"))
data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this, Please let me know if I misinterpreted your question:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
reduce( map(color_list$color, ~ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=drat)) +
  geom_line(color=.x)), `+`)
```

**Explanation:**
patchwork library uses plus operator to add plots together, knowing this we can use reduce to gather all the plots and adding them together similar to g1 + g2 + g3...., Note , I am saying similar not same, reduce essentially does reduces to one object by taking inputs at a time, then the result is again taken and to be applied with next object and so on.where g1 , g2 and g3 are ggplot objects. Here I have used mtcars data for doing the same. Here these g1, g2 , g3 and so on are created by map function by iterating over colors.

**Output**:
[image]